# Can one GMSA ( Group managed service account) be applied to multiple computers?

Tags: active-directory

I read that MSA cannot be applied to more than one computer, Can gMSA be linked to more than one computer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.
A GMSA is used to run a service, just like a normal user account; it has no explicit relationships to any specific computer; it is indeed a common scenario to use the same GMSA to run a distributed service on several computers (a "server farm").
However, you need to give the involved computers proper permissions to actually handle and use the GMSA; you'll find relevant information here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/getting-started-with-group-managed-service-accounts.